# Javascript - Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to do what the title says however this code does not function. Can anyone give any tips on how to make this return correctly?

```
function multiples(number) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= number; i++) {

  if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
    sum += i;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: "does not function" : Can you clarify that ?

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve] - you currently do not return anything and are missing expected and actual output

Comment: Probably the problem is you are not returning anything

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because basic topics as missing return statements have been covered more than enough on this and many others sites.

Comment: Did you call the function somewhere?

Comment: one liner: Array.apply(0, Array(end)).map((item, i) => i).reduce((acc, x) => x % 5 === 0 || x % 3 === 0 ? acc + x : acc, 0)

Answer (score 8):

You are just missing a `return` statement.

**Demo**

```js
function multiples(number) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= number; i++) {

    if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
      sum += i;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log( multiples(10) );
console.log( multiples(5) );
console.log( multiples(6) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const multiplies = (number) => {
    return Array.apply(null, {length: number}).map((v, i) => i).reduce((sum, i) => {
        return (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) ? sum + i : sum;
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sum = 0;
var number = 15;
for (var i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
        alert(i);
        sum += i;
    }
}

alert(sum); // 60
</script>
```